# Postscript file editing for changing Print parameters

Tags: file, postscript, editing

How to edit the Postscript file to update the Sets/No of Copies print parameter in PS file.What are different ways to edit PS file.I am programming in C#.Is it possible to pro grammatically edit Sets.

Answer (score 0):

PostScript is itself a programming language, so editing PostScript involves editing the program.

How to edit it ? Well a programmers editor is usually pretty useful, because PostScript programs can contain binary. Be careful not to permit line end translation, this will break compressed data, or binary image data.

I have no idea what you are referring to as 'Sets'.

Clearly its possible to 'programmatically' alter a PostScript program, in the same way as you could write an application to edit a C# program.

But since it **is** a program, you may find it more challenging than you expect. Unless all your PostScript programs are produced from the same source, the program will vary considerably; an application which can deal with a specific program generated by a particular PostScript producer will very likely not work with PostScript produced from any other producer.

The only real way to work out what a PostScript program is up to is to run a PostScript interpreter and pass the program into it.

However, depending what exactly you are trying to do, and how homogenous your input programs are, you may be able to use a simpler approach. If all your input programs are going to be DSC-compliant (a specific way of formatting PostScript programs) then you can potentially locate the part of the program which sets (for example) NumCopies and alter that.